# Two Filter Issue

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, css

I've noticed that on certain pages, two filters appear in the top right. One is styled properly (the bottom one), and the other isn't. I'd like to remove the top one (which isn't styled properly). Is there some CSS I can add to remove it?

Here are some sample URL's:

https://bndlstech.com/shop/

https://bndlstech.com/blog/category/health-living/

Thanks!

Comment: This is likely an issue with your theme. Its developer should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select.s-hidden {display: none !important;}
```

just add that on your style.css, it should be hiding the top one.

Comment: This worked perfect. Thanks!!!